# Properties - how to avoid code repetition

Tags: c#

When creating a class that will be used in a viewmodel for an application that follows the  MVVM pattern, I have to implement properties this way:

```
private string _MyStringPropertyA;
public string MyStringPropertyA
{
    get {return _MyStringPropertyA;}
    set 
    {
        _MyStringPropertyA=value;
        OnPropertyChanged(()=>MyStringPropertyA);
    }
}


private string _MyStringPropertyB;
public string MyStringPropertyB
{
    get {return _MyStringPropertyB;}
    set 
    {
        _MyStringPropertyB=value;
        OnPropertyChanged(()=>MyStringPropertyB);
    }
}
```

instead of the more simple

```
public string MyStringPropertyA {get;set;}
public string MyStringPropertyA {get;set;}
```

simply because I have to raise the event on the setter. Besides making my code longer, I think it has a code smell of copy-and-paste programming. What can I do to avoid this? Is it possible to construct a generic class like, I don't know, `MVVMEnabled<T>` which I can implement as:

```
public MVVMEnabled<string> MyStringPropertyA {get;set;}
public MVVMEnabled<string> MyStringPropertyB {get;set;}
```

so that the code in the generic class will ensure that the OnPropertyChanged fires when value is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where I work we do something similar to your `MVVMEnabled` suggestion and it works well.

The only thing to watch for is that the value of the property is now tucked away in a property of `MVVMEnabled` (value, for example), so you end up with a slightly more verbose binding expression, such as `{Binding MyStringPropertyA.Value}`

To do this have `MVVMEnabled` implement INotifyPropertyChanged. You'll need a property, say `Value` which is the value that will be managed (a string in your example):

```
public T Value
{
  get{return m_Value;}
  set
  {
    if(m_Value != value)
    {
      m_Value = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(()=>Value);
    }
  }
}
```

In your main class make your property read-only:

```
public MVVMEnabled<string> MyStringPropertyA {get;private set;}
```

And initialize it in the constructor:

```
public SomeModel()
{
  this.MyStringPropertyA = new MVVMEnabled<string>();
}
```

The reason it's read-only is because you'll alter the value via the `Value` property, never the `MVVMEnabled` property.

Now, when you need to change it do something like this:

```
this.MyStringPropertyA.Value = "hello, world";
```

And as long as your binding is this:

```
{Binding MyStringPropertyA.Value}
```

You should be ok.

Comment: Actually my question is **how** would you implement something like `MVVMEnabled<T>`. I have the concept in my mind, but cannot figure out how to code it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share how your workplace implements the `MVVMEnabled`-like approach?

Comment: Hmmm I am wondering if it would be possible to override the assignment operator to `MVVMEnabled<T>` generic so that you could set the Value field while binding to the property name itself.

Comment: Sorry, but I just realised that this raises the event for Value property, not MyStringPropertyA. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu - It won't matter! In your xaml you'll have bound to `MyStringPropertyA.Value` so any changes (eg `MyStringPropertyA.Value = "hello"`) will be handled correctly by the binding.

Comment: I posted a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385303/initializing-autoproperties-of-object-using-reflection-any-caveats) about this after I implemented your solution (thanks!). Basically I wanted to get rid of the initializers in the constructor, so I used a little trick. I would appreciate it if you had a look.

Answer (score 1):

Well i would suggest you to create code snippets, that way it wont take much effort to write down multiple properties.

Comment: It's not just the effort I am worried about, it's the way it makes the code more verbose and repetitive to read than necessary and making it hard to stick to DRY. If I was not firing the OnPropertyChanged, I would be done in two lines of code. There should be a way to factor out the event firing, I am almost sure. I just don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think something like this would work - at least I've never seen such a thing before.

Instead, you could use Aspect-Oriented Programming with [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) to do it:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged] 
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyStringPropertyA {get;set;}
    public string MyStringPropertyA {get;set;}

    // ...
```

Comment: How does PostSharp do it? I am more interested in the behind the scenes logic of how such an attribute could be implemented.

Comment: AFAIK PostSharp inserts the `OnPropertyChanged(...)` code behind the scenes during compilation. So there's no principal difference, it's only much shorter and easier.